# Swizzling operations in Direct3D pixel shader assembly language

Tags: assembly, shader, gpu, direct3d, hlsl

I wrote a pixel shader (version 3.0) and compiled it with fxc command. There were no problems with compilation, but there is a thing which I cannot understand.

There were some swizzling operations which have behaviour which is undocumented. Here's an example:

add r1.xyz, -r0.z, c3

(r1.xyz has length 3, -r0.z has length 1 and c3 has length 4)

Anyone knows which value will be writen to each of vector components of r1 when operand/result register lengths are not the same?

Documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172242(v=vs.85).aspx is not clear about this case.
Some parts of documentation say that if operand has fewer channel letters than result, last letter is repeated. However, it does not states what happens when operand has more letters than result or operand does not have letters at all (and result does not have 4 components).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result will be:
r1.xyz = -r0.zzz + c3.xyz

Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219869(v=vs.85).aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219870(v=vs.85).aspx